# Downgrade from WINDOWS 8 PRO RTM X64 BUILD: 6.2.9200.16384.WIN8_RTM.120725-124 to windows 7 ultimate without formatting

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, downgrade

how to downgrade from Win 8 Pro to Win 7 ultimate without formatting.
i had win 7 ultimate. I updated it to win 8 build 9200. now i wan to downgrade to my previous version of win 7.
How to do that without formatting??
please help

Comment: This cannot be done unless you made clone image of your system before you upgraded to Windows 8.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to downgrade without formatting.

Backup your data, format, and reinstall Windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

Try it with the help of the Windows.old folder:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971760/en

Answer (score 1):

The files which consist of Windows 7 have been overwritten by the files which consist of Windows 8. In order to restore those files, you need to copy them from somewhere: i.e. the Windows 7 install disc. Thus, the only way to 'downgrade' from Windows 8 to Windows 7 is to reinstall.